# Transfer data from Vuejs component to another div

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to transfer some data?

In my vue component (child) i have:

```
{{ checked.length }}
```

Responsible for the number of selected items.

But i need to show that information in another `div`(parent vue), which is not in the view component.

upd: child component

```
<template>
<ul class='filter-content__list' v-if='toggle'>
 {{ checked.length }}
<li v-for='item in itemsData' :key='item.id'>
  <label class='custom-checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' :value='item.title' v-model='checked'>
    <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
  </label>
 </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>

export default ({
 props: ['toggle', 'itemsData'],
 data() {
  return {
   checked: []
   };
  }
 });
```

Comment: emit events and listen events.

Comment: Already tried, but wont work for me. I think because i have 3-4 lists (list = child component). Or i did something wrong

Comment: this.$root.$emit('checkedItems', checked.length) than this.$root.$listen('checkedItems', (payload) => {})

Comment: Please don't paste a picture of the code. Paste the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values between components as a property check the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

**N.B:**

There is only one-way-down binding, i.e:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around.